# How to Create Extension Form View in Python Side?

Tags: python, xpath, orm, odoo, odoo-view

I am trying to create dynamic view ,  so i want to create views in python side . But when i try to save the view the "arch_base" field is not set . Can someone tell me what's the problem ? Here is my function

```
@api.onchange('field_id')
def create_validation_button(self):
    model = self.field_id.model_id.model
    model_view = self.env['ir.ui.view'].search([("model", "=", model), ('type', "=", "form")])
    arch = '<xpath expr="//header" postition="inside"><button string="Add Followers" type="object" name="add_project_followers" /></xpath>'
    if model_view:
        self.view_id = None
        self.env['ir.ui.view'].search(
            [("model", "=", model), ('name', "=", 'validation.' + model_view.name)]).unlink()
        view_data = {'name': 'validation.' + model_view.name, 'type': 'form', 'model': model, 'priority': 1,
                     'inherit_id': model_view.id,
                     'mode': 'extension',
                     'arch_base': arch.encode('utf-8')}
        view = self.env["ir.ui.view"].create(view_data)
        self.view_id = view
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: What are you trying to do with the dynamic view? And why not just create a view in XML? Additionally, can you include the code that is executed by your `add_project_followers` method?

Comment: I want to create a validation button on views chosen by the user . At this time let's just suppose that `add_project_followers` prints something on the console . When `create_validation_button` is executed the view is created and assigned to his parent but there only the `arch_base` who is not set .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the field name is `arch` not `arch_base` so the set will be :

```
view_data = {'name': 'validation.' + model_view.name, 'type': 'form', 'model': model, 'priority': 1,
                     'inherit_id': model_view.id,
                     'mode': 'extension',
                     'arch': arch.encode('utf-8')}
```

Thanks to

> Peter Alabaster
>   https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/how-to-create-extension-form-view-in-python-side-119479